# How to send email from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, win32com

i have an email function to send multiple emails for that i need to call that function and **i need response**  from that function whether the email is sent or canceled by the user

```
def send_mail_report(reporting_message, to_email, msg_subject):
    olMailItem = 0x0
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    newMail.Subject = msg_subject
    newMail.Body = reporting_message
    newMail.To = to_email
    SEND_EMAIL = newMail.display()
    time.sleep(16)
    if SEND_EMAIL:
        return "Sent"
    else:
        return "Failed"
```

i need to get response from this function

Comment: I would recommend https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib

Comment: what happens when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code

```
import smtplib    
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host,25)    
server.sendmail('sender','email_recepient','msg')
```